Are the Buddhist 8 hot hells and 8 cold hells ordered together into one list?
I am reading about these in Buddhist Cosmology, and am wondering if they are ordered together (hot and cold) into one sequential list, where it goes (from least severe to most severe):

top cold (slight pain)
bottom cold
top hot
bottom hot (pure pain)

The cold seems like less pain than the hot, as you can easily experience chattering teeth, and even blisters, in normal routine life. Get down to frostbite and you don't really feel it because you are numb. But enter hot hell, and you immediately are killed and revived over and over again, all the way to pure pain.
But maybe they don't move in a sequence as one, and are just two interwoven or separate progressions? How does it work exactly.

You may find a good explanation to your question in the book titled "Words of my Perfect Teacher" by Patrul Rinpoche. In part 1, chapter 3 titled "The defects of samsara" 18 hells are described, starting from 8 hot hells to 8 cold hells to Ephemeral hells. For example, in the introduction to 8 hot hells, it is written [paraphrased] 'The hot hells lie one over the other (like floors of a building)'. The section particularly deals with the sequence and location. I hope you find this useful.
